# How to find the application folder on android?

Tags: java, android, file

I created an application that writes and reads data from a file. I need to find this text document outside the program. I think the file can be found in the application folder, but I can not find it. The application works, but I can’t find the folder.

I was looking for my application along the way: Android\data... 
not there. Moreover, I searched in all possible folders but without result.

Writing and reading this way

```
void writeFile(String text)
    {
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE)));
            bw.write(text);
            bw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void readFile() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    openFileInput(FILENAME)));
            text.setText("");
            String str = "";
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.setText(text.getText() + str);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you save the file in external or internal storage? Does your other app declare the correct permissions to read that file?

Comment: How can I find out in which storage the file is saved?

Comment: Can you show your `openFileOutput(...)` method? Is this on Android?

Comment: Yes, Android. In what sense to show? This is the same method from the java.io.FileOutputStream;

Comment: @SliceOfGray You call a function named `openFileOutput()` in the code you gave here. Where is that function defined?